# where clausule on field defined by sub-query

Tags: mysql

I have this query which displays some properties and count the number of references to it from an other table:

```
SELECT 
       p.id,p.propName
       (
         SELECT COUNT(*) FROM propLoc WHERE propLoc.propID = p.id
       ) AS number
FROM property as p 
WHERE p.category != 'natural'
```

This generates a good table with all the information I want to filter:

```
id | propName | number
3  | Name 1   | 3
4  | Name 2   | 1
5  | Name 3   | 0
6  | Name 4   | 10
etc etc
```

I now want to filter out the properties with number <= 0
So I tried to add an `AND number > 0` But it reacts with `Unknown column 'number' in 'where clause'` apparently you can't filter on a name specified by a subquery?

**How can I achieve my goal?**

Comment: An SQL statement does not execute from top-to-bottom. The `WHERE` clause is logically processed before the `SELECT` clause, which means that no column named `number` exists yet. See Itzik Ben-Gan's [Logical Query Procesing](http://www.sql.co.il/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf) diagram for an explanation of all the logical query processing steps. Some of the steps are specific to SQL Server, but it's general enough to be useful for MySQL. I don't know if there is an equivalent diagram for the MySQL engine.

Comment: @isme: The pdf is great (but I would expect `TOP` to be processed together with `ORDER BY`).

Comment: @ypercube I don't know how SQL Server or MySQL implements it physically. You might be right about `ORDER BY` and `TOP` being processed together. The point of the diagram is to show the logical steps. The database engine is free to do whatever it likes as long as the result is the same as following the logical processing steps.

Comment: @isme: yeah, I agree, these are the logical not actual steps. But you can't limit the Top n rows, if you haven't ordered them first. In the 2012 version, they have added the standard `OFFSET / FETCH` syntax in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @ypercube You can use `TOP` without `ORDER BY`: `SELECT TOP (1) * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;`. It will return any one row from the table. The order is unspecified, so the result is non-deterministic. The selected row in practice might be repeatable in a given environment, but it depends entirely on the implementation of the database engine and and the state and structure of database.

Comment: @isme: I don't disagree. Still, the `TOP` is applied after the `ORDER BY` (when there is an ORDER BY). When there isn't, the results are non-deterministic, as you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline subquery you have is equivalent with a `LEFT JOIN`. Rewrite your query as a Join, and make it an `INNER` one. Either this way:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.propName
     , grp.number
FROM property AS p 
  INNER JOIN 
     ( SELECT propID 
            , COUNT(*) AS number
       FROM propLoc
       GROUP BY propID
     ) AS grp 
    ON grp.propID = p.id
WHERE p.category <> 'natural' ;
```

or this:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.propName
     , COUNT(*) AS number
FROM property AS p 
  INNER JOIN propLoc 
    ON propLoc.propID = p.id
WHERE p.category <> 'natural' 
GROUP BY p.id ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this::

```
SELECT 
       p.id,p.propName, count(1) as number
FROM property as p 
inner join propLoc on (propLoc.propID = p.id)
WHERE p.category != 'natural'
group BY p.id
```

Comment: It's fine now. Removing my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

when `WHERE` dosn't work, ofen `HAVNING` works, as it filter the result later in the chain

```
SELECT 
       p.id,p.propName
       (
         SELECT COUNT(*) FROM propLoc WHERE propLoc.propID = p.id
       ) AS number
FROM property as p 
WHERE p.category != 'natural'
HAVING number > 0
```

Comment: It works, but it makes the query 'very' slow: 0.15 seconds to retrieve 506 records. While the join statement of @ypercube does it in 0.0062 seconds.

Comment: i just provided a easy way to rewrite his query, not the fastest :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id,p.propName,count(p.id) as number
FROM property as p 
inner join propLoc prop WHERE prop.propID = p.id
WHERE p.category != 'natural'
group p.id;
```

OR

```
SELECT p.id,p.propName,count(p.id) as number
FROM property as p 
left join propLoc prop WHERE prop.propID = p.id
WHERE p.category != 'natural' and number > 0
group p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       p.id,p.propName,q.number
       from
       (
         SELECT propID,COUNT(*) as number FROM propLoc WHERE propLoc.propID = p.id
       ) q join
 property as p 
on q.propID=p.id
 where p.category != 'natural'
```